# Algorithm to find the next number in a sequence of numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math

I have the following sequence of numbers:

```
2 5 6 20 18 80 54 320 162 1280
```

I'm just not able to find the next following number or the algorithm to calculate it.

Any hints?

Comment: sometimes it's good to use OEIS http://oeis.org/search?q=2+5+6+20+18+80+54+&sort=&language=english&go=Search but I don't see your sequence there.

Comment: According to Nassim Taleb (author of Fooled by Randomness), this task is impossible. The best you can do is spot A pattern and apply a heuristic. I think it is possible to come up with a sequence of the same length which can be obtained using 2-3 different formulas.

Comment: The next number is 42.  I promise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The next number is `486`.

The sequence is *3, *4.

Every odd index is multiplied by 4:

```
5 20 80 320 1280
```

Every even index is multiplied by 3:

```
2 6 18 54 162
```

Thus, `486` is the next number. :-)

Comment: nicely spotted! Although, I think you just did someone's homework

Comment: Good one. I find it difficult to derive meanings out of sequences.

Answer (score 9):

The next is 486

Just [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+5+6+20+18+80+54+320+162+1280)

Mathematica output : `{2, 5, 6, 20, 18, 80, 54, 320, 162, 1280, 486, 5120, 1458, 20480, 4374}`

and here is recurrence relation it gives :

```
a(n+4) = 7*a(n+2)-12*a(n)
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice and easy solution ;)

Comment: wolfram is much more clever than me in finding the recurrence relations :)

Comment: I'll definitely bookmark this for another question like this. Just so I don't have to think next time.

Comment: You are goddamn right, thanks for your introduce best website. <3

Answer (score 4):

This problem is underdetermined.  You could write a program to come up with some logical next number, but there's no guarantee that it would have anything to do with what the puzzle intended.  For example, the computer could fit a tenth-order polynomial to the data, then use it to extrapolate to the next value.  It could try to find some text corpus that would have these numbers appear in the name of the text, then return the first letter of that corpus.  In other words, yes, the computer could come up with some number that fits, but because the puzzlemaker is looking for some specific answer there's no reason to think the computer would be right.

That said, the answer to the puzzle involves looking at the ratios of the odd-indexed terms and the ratio of the even-indexed terms.  You'll spot a pattern.  :-)

Comment: Another correct solution is 0.  The corresponding rule:  "The series as specified, followed by an infinite number of 0s."

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Java application that calculates that sequence:

```
/**
 * @author mpieciukiewicz
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int p=0; p<11; p++) {
            System.out.println(p+":"+number(p));
        }
    }

    private int calculate(int base, int multiplier, int power) {
        int result = base;
        for (int p=0; p<power; p++) {
            result = result * multiplier;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int number(int index) {
       int half = index / 2;
       int number;
       if (index%2 == 0) {
           number = calculate(2, 3, half);
       } else {
           number = calculate(5, 4, half);
       }
       return number;
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
0:2
1:5
2:6
3:20
4:18
5:80
6:54
7:320
8:162
9:1280
10:486
```

So the answer for your question is: 468.

Comment: Wow. But why go through such lengths?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Sloane's Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/Seis.html). This is what professional mathematicians use as their starting point.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
a1=2
a2=4
a3=a1*3
a4=a2*4
a5=a3*3
a6=a4*4
```

generally:

```
a(2k+1)=a(2k-1)*3
a(2k)=a(2k-2)*4
```

Answer (score 0):

51,128 is the next number. there is no convergence in the differentiated rows so the triangle is reduce to 16,125.

Answer (score 0):

Next is 486

separate the 2 sequences  from that list of numbers 2 5 6 20 18 80 54 320 162 1280

```
2   6   18  54  162 
5   20  80  320 1280    

1st row is 3x   4th row is 4 x 
so next in sequence is 3x 162      and next number is 4x 1280
```