# What is the formula for the following sequence? 123, 624, 693, 4812, etc

Tags: algorithm, series

In an online event, we have to frame an algorithm to generate a series as given below..., 
For input 6, the algorithm has to generate.....

123
624
693
4812
15510
12186.

we thought a lot and really frustrated about the algorithm.
Could any one help us...

EDIT: Got Algorithm. Thanks to Irit katriel

Comment: Uhh... so... you're told the answer for 6 and you have to figure out the general case algorithm?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like the i-th number is composed of i,2*i and 3*i, concatenated. The order of concatenation is shifted by 1 each time.

Comment: That's an exact match for the relation between the groups. How the input `6` comes into this is another matter... Perhaps factorisation, as 1*2*3 = 6, or 6 being the number of groups generated...

Comment: +1 Nice job. Even [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=123+624+693+4812+15510+12186) cannot answer this.

Comment: @Linus Kleen ...? I don't think Wolfram Alpha is meant to be able to solve something like this. You code right? You're on SO. So you should realise that if you give a piece of software a random string of numbers, it won't spit out the solution to a puzzle.

Comment: @Irit Katriel  really its very great man! I really wonder how you thought this in a just 4 minutes. Very great.

Comment: @quasiverse I beg to differ. The series in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722403/algorithm-to-find-the-next-number-in-a-sequence-of-numbers/4722469#4722469) can be solved by WA. And yes, I code. Those guys at Wolfram Labs do, too. Their software is *exactly* meant to solve this.

Comment: @Linus Kleen Okay, maybe (and maybe not) so. I believe the sequence in your example is very different in that it's just a sequence with arithmetic changes. This sequence has string manipulations. I don't think WA was designed to solve sequences with string manipulations.